# Background initialization of xlwings add-in

Tags: xlwings

I have created an Excel add-in with xlwings. When the user first uses the add-in, say by clicking a button in its ribbon panel, there is a one-time cost as xlwings launches Python for the first time. I am wondering if there is a way for this to happen in the background when the add-in loads but without freezing Excel, so that when the user clicks a button in the add-in for the first time the Python connection has already been made and the first response is quicker.